# Unwanted space beetween border and content filled with background-image or colors

Tags: html, css, background, border

Working on a procedural moodboard generator, i'm facing a CSS rendering problem.

This is a screen showing in red squares the element with problems (you may need to open the image and zoom on full size to understand):
[image: CSS border space on div]

There is like half a pixel space between the div top limit and content, so we can see background-image overflowing. It does the same with some colors (like Red).
Beeing a bit perfectinist and as it's a visual tool, i really would love a clean render.

Here is a codepen with an exemple :
[Codepen link to the HTML / CSS code](https://codepen.io/camillewemajin/pen/JjWeWOL)

```css
.moodboard {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 4em;
  position: relative;
}

.whiteborder {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '';
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0.8em;
  z-index: 20;
}

.color,
.image,
.font {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0.8em;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.font .content {
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0.2em;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.image .content {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.line {
  display: table;
  width: 100vw;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.line div {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<section class="moodboard relative">
  <span class="whiteborder"></span>
  <article class='line' style='height: 33.333333333333vh'>
    <div class='font'>
      <span class='content' style='font-family: &quot;Seaweed Script&quot;, cursive'>Lorem Ipsum</span>
    </div>
    <div class='color'>
      <span class='content' style='background-color: rgb(239, 152, 170) ; height: 100%;width : 100%;'></span>

    </div>
    <div class='color'>
      <span class='content' style='background-color: rgb(250, 231, 181) ; height: 100%;width : 100%;'></span>

    </div>
    <div class='color' style="min-width:0 ;">
      <span class='content' style='background-color: rgb(197, 208, 230) ; height: 42vh;width : 42vh;border-radius:50%; z-index:3;'></span>

    </div>
  </article>
  <article class='line' style='height: 33.333333333333vh'>
    <div class='font'>
      <span class='content' style='font-family: &quot;Dancing Script&quot;, cursive'>Lorem Ipsum</span>
    </div>
    <div class='image'>
      <span class='content' style=' background-color:red;height:50vh;width : 100%;'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='font'>
      <span class='content' style='font-family: &quot;Amatic SC&quot;, cursive'>Lorem Ipsum</span>
    </div>
    <div class='image'>
      <span class='content' style=' background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a6/ea/9b/a6ea9b7774c776f6d3e81c224a3550e2.jpg);height:58.333333333333vh;width : 100%;'></span>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class='line' style='height: 33.333333333333vh'>
    <div class='image'>
      <span class='content' style=' background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a6/ea/9b/a6ea9b7774c776f6d3e81c224a3550e2.jpg);height:41.666666666667vh;width : 100%;'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='image'>
      <span class='content' style=' background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a6/ea/9b/a6ea9b7774c776f6d3e81c224a3550e2.jpg);height:66.666666666667vh;width : 100%;'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='color'>
      <span class='content' style='background-color: rgb(255, 188, 217) ; height: 100%;width : 100%;'></span>

    </div>
  </article>

</section>
```

Sorry for the messy HTML tag with inline style, but the full display result from a backend script.

I've open the page on Edge and got the same half-pixel space. Same for Opera, even worse, all the div side are facing the issue. So maybe it come from something i'm doing wrong with box-sizing ?

[image: Worse on Opera...]

I'm thinking about adding a white "fake border patch" fixed over each element with :after to hide the unwanted space, but wanted to ask you before using such a trivial solution...

Is there some CSS property or an other elegant way to remove this space before the border ?

Comment: remove your border from .content  maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the borders properties on the `.content` class

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Or reduce the size of the `border-width` property

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 1px;
  ...
}
```